# Is it possible to get doctring of coroutine?

Tags: python, discord.py, docstring

I got a function defined by:

```py
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    """
        return pong
    """
    await ctx.send("pong !")
```

But I would take its doctring to make a better function help than the discord module. How could I have docstring?

I tried:

```
__doc__ ( inside ping function )
ping.__doc__
```

Comment: `ping.__doc__` is supposed to work if the `@bot.command()` decorator behaves well.

Comment: if I try outside the func, it's return me the __doc__ of @bot.command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from [the implementation of `command`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/bb1c1e9fa3b80b55166817e1e7f828d9a76c0ff1/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1281-L1319) that your `func` is wrapped in a `Command` object:

```
def command(name=None, cls=None, **attrs):
    """..."""
    if cls is None:
        cls = Command

    def decorator(func):
        if isinstance(func, Command):
            raise TypeError('Callback is already a command.')
        return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)

    return decorator
```

The docstring of that decorator states that:

> By default the `help` attribute is received automatically from the
>   docstring of the function and is cleaned up with the use of
>   `inspect.cleandoc`. If the docstring is `bytes`, then it is decoded
>   into `str` using utf-8 encoding.

You can see this happen in [the implementation of `Command`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/bb1c1e9fa3b80b55166817e1e7f828d9a76c0ff1/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L219-L227), so you should be able to see your docstring via `ping.help`.